# syntax error in the below JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
    var valid = true;
     if ( document.<portlet:namespace/>fm.<portlet:namespace/>eventName.value == "" ){
         alert ( "Please Give a valid Event Name!" );
         document.<portlet:namespace/>fm.<portlet:namespace/>eventName.focus();
          valid = false;
     }
     else if ( document.<portlet:namespace/>fm.<portlet:namespace/>triggerOfEvent.value == "" ){
         document.<portlet:namespace/>fm.<portlet:namespace/>triggerOfEvent.focus();
         alert ( "Please select Trigger of Event" );
           valid = false;
     } 
     else ( document.<portlet:namespace/>fm.<portlet:namespace/>nextEvent.value == "" ){
         document.<portlet:namespace/>fm.<portlet:namespace/>nextEvent.focus();
         alert ( "Please select Trigger of Event" );
           valid = false;
     } 
    return valid;
}

</script>
```

This script showing the syntax error like return invalid,statement missing, these type error coming.... 
I missed any thing...can you please let me know friends.....

I am working on liferay portlet development....

Comment: Would be more useful to see the rendered JS.

Comment: I think you should tell us on what platform this JavaScript code is running.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your portlet namespace is correct, then the code you posted is correct too.

If you have spelling mistakes in the form fields, you will get errors in the code.
Additionally if the portlet replacement code does not work (please show the view-source of code and form) then it will fail

I replaced the portlet vars with XXX for testing and came up with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
    var valid = true;
     if ( document.XXXfm.XXXeventName.value == "" ){
         alert ( "Please Give a valid Event Name!" );
         document.XXXfm.XXXeventName.focus();
          valid = false;
     }
     else if ( document.XXXfm.XXXtriggerOfEvent.value == "" ){
         document.XXXfm.XXXtriggerOfEvent.focus();
         alert ( "Please select Trigger of Event" );
           valid = false;
     } 
     else ( document.XXXfm.XXXnextEvent.value == "" ){
         document.XXXfm.XXXnextEvent.focus();
         alert ( "Please select Trigger of Event" );
           valid = false;
     } 
    return valid;
}

</script>
```

which is valid code.

I rewrote it to be simpler and to avoid the form name by passing the form object:

`<form onsubmit="return validate(this)">`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5Hvtm/)

```
function validate(theForm){
     if (theForm.XXXeventName.value == "" ){
         alert ( "Please Give a valid Event Name!" );
         theForm.XXXeventName.focus();
         return false;
     }
     if (theForm.XXXtriggerOfEvent.value == "" ){
         theForm.XXXtriggerOfEvent.focus();
         alert ( "Please select Trigger of Event" );
         return false;
     }
     if (theForm.XXXnextEvent.value == "" ){
         theForm.XXXnextEvent.focus();
         alert ( "Please select Trigger of Event" );
         return false;
     }
    return true;
}
```